# FabricJS Touch Pan/Zoom Entire Canvas

Tags: canvas, fabricjs

I need to enable touch zoom/panning on a FabricJS canvas. There are libraries that will allow this behavior on an image (see [pinch-zoom-canvas](https://github.com/vash15/pinch-zoom-canvas)) or via mouse-click events (see [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gncabrera/hkee5L6d/5/)) but I can't seem to get the 'touch:gesture' events hooked up properly.

I've built the library with gestures enabled (so [this FabricJS](http://fabricjs.com/touch-events) demo works locally for me), but I don't know where to start with combining the gestures with the working fiddle.

I tried variations of code like this:

```
    canvas.on({
        'touch:gesture': function() {
            var text = document.createTextNode(' Gesture ');
            info.insertBefore(text, info.firstChild);
            // Handle zoom only if 2 fingers are touching the screen
            if (event.e.touches && event.e.touches.length == 2) {
                // Get event point
                var point = new fabric.Point(event.self.x, event.self.y);
                // Remember canvas scale at gesture start
                if (event.self.state == "start") {
                    zoomStartScale = self.canvas.getZoom();
                }
                // Calculate delta from start scale
                var delta = zoomStartScale * event.self.scale;
                // Zoom to pinch point
                self.canvas.zoomToPoint(point, delta);
            }

        },
        'touch:drag': function(e) {
            panning = true;
            var text = document.createTextNode(' Dragging ');
            info.insertBefore(text, info.firstChild);
            if (panning && e && e.e) {
                debugger;
                var units = 10;
                var delta = new fabric.Point(e.e.movementX, e.e.movementY);
                canvas.relativePan(delta);
            }
            panning = false;
        },
        'touch:longpress': function() {
            var text = document.createTextNode(' Longpress ');
            info.insertBefore(text, info.firstChild);
        }
    });
```

But nothing happens when I test on iPhone/iPad.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The pinch to zoom was a stupid mistake, I hadn't included the event in the function parameter. The code below is working for pinch/zoom and tap/drag.

```
    canvas.on({
        'touch:gesture': function(e) {
            if (e.e.touches && e.e.touches.length == 2) {
                pausePanning = true;
                var point = new fabric.Point(e.self.x, e.self.y);
                if (e.self.state == "start") {
                    zoomStartScale = self.canvas.getZoom();
                }
                var delta = zoomStartScale * e.self.scale;
                self.canvas.zoomToPoint(point, delta);
                pausePanning = false;
            }
        },
        'object:selected': function() {
            pausePanning = true;
        },
        'selection:cleared': function() {
            pausePanning = false;
        },
        'touch:drag': function(e) {
            if (pausePanning == false && undefined != e.e.layerX && undefined != e.e.layerY) {
                currentX = e.e.layerX;
                currentY = e.e.layerY;
                xChange = currentX - lastX;
                yChange = currentY - lastY;

                if( (Math.abs(currentX - lastX) <= 50) && (Math.abs(currentY - lastY) <= 50)) {
                    var delta = new fabric.Point(xChange, yChange);
                    canvas.relativePan(delta);
                }

                lastX = e.e.layerX;
                lastY = e.e.layerY;
            }
        }
    });
```

The absolute ~50px if/then statement is to avoid drags far away from the last point causing the canvas to jump. Also paused the panning to be able to move object independently. Pinch/zoom code was found in a [github issues thread](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/2658).

Comment: awesome one! really a great help for all fabric users!

Comment: Got some question: I tried this answer, but my `canvas` is not receiving `touch:gesture`, it seems that only objects are receiving `touch:gesture`? Would really like to know how does your canvas receive the `touch:gesture` event, thanks! I'm using 1.7.20 (with build_with_gestures), by the way.

Comment: Is it possible to zoom only elements? I would like to zoom the whole page if I try to zoom on the canvas background.

Comment: @Simone you could probably use 'object:hover' to change the scale of the object. I'd create a separate question though to outline your desired functionality

Answer (score 4):

I had some trouble getting the panning part of Laurens code to work on `Fabric 2.3.3`. So in case anyone encounters the same problem I wanted to share my solution.

My problem was, that I could not get panning to work on my smartphone, even though it worked on a pc. After some debugging I found that I can solve it by replacing `e.e.layerX` with `e.self.x` (and `e.e.layerY` with `e.self.y`).

Heres the full modified code:

```
canvas.on({
    'touch:gesture': function(e) {
        if (e.e.touches && e.e.touches.length == 2) {
            pausePanning = true;
            var point = new fabric.Point(e.self.x, e.self.y);
            if (e.self.state == "start") {
                zoomStartScale = canvas.getZoom();
            }
            var delta = zoomStartScale * e.self.scale;
            canvas.zoomToPoint(point, delta);
            pausePanning = false;
        }
    },
    'object:selected': function() {
        pausePanning = true;
    },
    'selection:cleared': function() {
        pausePanning = false;
    },
    'touch:drag': function(e) {
        if (pausePanning == false && undefined != e.self.x && undefined != e.self.x) {
            currentX = e.self.x;
            currentY = e.self.y;
            xChange = currentX - lastX;
            yChange = currentY - lastY;

            if( (Math.abs(currentX - lastX) <= 50) && (Math.abs(currentY - lastY) <= 50)) {
                var delta = new fabric.Point(xChange, yChange);
                canvas.relativePan(delta);
            }

            lastX = e.self.x;
            lastY = e.self.y;
        }
    }
});}
```

Comment: THANK YOU for this!!! I too had issues getting canvas panning to work and this fixed it.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to achieve  multi-touch panning and zooming with the mouse:wheel event.

When doing pinch to zoom - [most browsers](https://medium.com/@auchenberg/detecting-multi-touch-trackpad-gestures-in-javascript-a2505babb10e) usually emit the `ctrl` button as well to distinguish between a scroll operation and not.

I then utilize the DeltaX and DeltaY properties of the Fabric event to either zoom or pan similar to the [sample](http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-5) code they provided.

Every place that I call `setState` below should be a variable outside the function if you are not using with React.

```js
    this.canvas.on("mouse:wheel", opt => {
      if (!this.canvas.viewportTransform) {
        return;
      }

      var evt: any = opt.e;
      if (evt.ctrlKey === true) {
        var evt: any = opt.e;
        var deltaY = evt.deltaY;
        var zoom = this.canvas.getZoom();
        zoom = zoom - deltaY / 100;
        if (zoom > 20) zoom = 20;
        if (zoom < 0.01) zoom = 0.01;
        this.canvas.zoomToPoint(
          new fabric.Point(evt.offsetX, evt.offsetY),
          zoom
        );
      } else {
        console.log("Scrolling!!");

        //inverted scrolling enabled. Remove the -1 multiplier to disable

        this.canvas.viewportTransform[4] += (evt.deltaX)*-1; 
        this.canvas.viewportTransform[5] += (evt.deltaY)*-1;
        this.canvas.requestRenderAll();
        this.setState({ lastPosX: evt.clientX });
        this.setState({ lastPosY: evt.clientY });
      }
      opt.e.preventDefault();
      opt.e.stopPropagation();
    });
```