# FabricJS, How to implement touch controls in fabric js

Tags: fabricjs

I have tried the answer from:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45131912/12114516

But, when I try to drag my canvas around, only blue box appear. So I tried to console log when touch even was registered, and that did not work. This blue drag box covers touch command
This is what I see when i try to drag: 
[image]

**ANSER IS HERE:**
 I digged around for a bit and found out that the demo:http://fabricjs.com/touch-events

IS USING ANOTHER JS FILE: http://fabricjs.com/lib/fabric_with_gestures.js so what I just go to that website, ctrl+a, ctrl+c, make a new script file, ctrl+v and link my default-fabric js file from html to the new js file instead so how my script src looks like this:

```js
<script src="/script/fabric_with_touch.js"></script>
```

Remeber that "fabric_with_touch.js" is a file I created and copy and pasted the website contents into. And don't worry, it won't mess with your mouse or keyboard controls.

Comment: make `cavas.selection = false`

Comment: I already tried that, it just makes the canvas untargetable

Comment: you can download customised builds of fabric from here : http://fabricjs.com/build/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welp, I digged around for a bit and found out that the demo:http://fabricjs.com/touch-events

IS USING ANOTHER JS FILE: 
http://fabricjs.com/lib/fabric_with_gestures.js
so what I just go to that website, ctrl+a, ctrl+c, make a new script file, ctrl+v
and link my default-fabric js file from html to the new js file instead
so how my script src looks like this:

```html
<script src="/script/fabric_with_touch.js"></script>
```

Remeber that "fabric_with_touch.js" is a file I created and copy and pasted the website contents into.
And don't worry, it won't mess with your mouse or keyboard controls, I have tried that too